# Dashlets not available to be added to Dashboard

Tags: permissions, acl, dashlet

2 roles in Drupal, 2 groups in CiviCRM, 2 roles in CiviCRM

- administrators
- members of the board

permissions in Drupal

- administrators: all permissions
- members of the board: all, except some (see list at the end)

Administrator created some contact reports - in fact status reports on new contacts and open activities (tasks to do) - and defined them as dashlets. They can be added on the dashboard of administrator, but do not appear to be added an the dashboard of the members of the board.

Also, the members do not see the entry "Contact Reports" in the drop down menu "CiviReport", although they can see them when selecting "show all reports".

Which ACL do I need to add in CiviCRM "Manage ACL's", so that the board members can see and add the dashlets?

=== === ===

Members of the board do not have a Drupal permission for:

- import contacts
- remove contacts
- import SQL datasource
- manage CiviCRM
- IDS control bypass
- translate CiviCRM
- manage dedupe rules
- join double contacts
- force joining doble contacts
- show debug output
- use Ajax-API
- create manual batch
- edit own manual batch
- show own manual batch
- show all manual batches
- manage payment methods
- edit own API-keys

CiviEvent

- remove event
- manage event profiles

CiviContribute

CiviMember

- remove in CiviMember

CiviMail

- remove mailing

CiviReport

- show report SQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I recall correctly, this is down to some peculiarity of the dashlet permissions.  If you go to the **Access** tab of the report in question, you'll see two ways to set the permissions (see screenshot below).  However, I believe only the "permission" setting will control access to the dashlet.  Try setting both the Role ("Board Member") and the permission (to any permission the board members have) and you should be good to go.

[image]

Comment: This was it! You made my day (in fact a few days, as I was looking why the dashlet did not appear since a few days). Thanks @JonG

Comment: I still have a question: why do the board members do not get the "Contact reports" entry in the dropdown menu "Reports"? While, when they select "All reports", they do get the contact reports... All other 4 items in the dropdown list are visible: contribution, events, mailing, members... only "Contact reports" is missing. Where to find the permission for this menu link?

Comment: Hi @MarkDQ - could you please ask that as a separate question?  That will help others with the same problem to find it more easily.